# How can I solve $y''+y'\tan x-y\cos^2x=2\cos^4x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The original form is:
$$(d^2y/dx^2)\cos x+(dy/dx)\sin x-y\cos^3x=2\cos^5x$$
And after some simplifying I got $$y''+y'\tan x-y\cos^2x=2\cos^4x$$
But seems like I can't solve it with all the textbooks I searched for some clue.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please try to provide some background to your question (where does it come from? which book have you read? is it a homework?) and provide some efforts (what have you tried?). It will help us to give you the best help as possible.

Comment: It seems that $y_p(x) = e^{\sin x}$ is a particular solution for the homogeneous ODE.

Comment: Particular solution by eye-balling $y_p(x) = -2\cos^2x + 4$

Comment: It's a homework, I've studied some non-Eng books so I didn't mention them. And my progress was only until the later equation, I couldn't go further. And thanks for all the helps

Answer (score 2):

The equation is singular at $\frac\pi2+k\pi$, so around $x=0$ one can parametrize with $y(x)=z(\sin x)$. Then
\begin{align}
y'(x)&=\cos x\,z'(\sin x)\\
y''(x)&=\cos^2x\,z''(\sin(x))-\sin x\,z'(x)\\
\hline
\cos x\,y''(x)+\sin x\,y'(x)&=\cos^3x\,z''(\sin(x))\\
&=2\cos^5x+\cos^3z(\sin(x))\\
\,z''(\sin(x))-z(\sin(x))&=2\cos^2x=2(1-\sin^2x)\\
\hline
\implies
z''(s)-z(s)&=2(1-s^2)
\end{align}
This now is a standard linear DE with constant coefficients.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's easy to undrestand now.

Answer (score 2):

After change $t=\sin x$ we get ode
$$y''-y=2(1-t^2)$$
with solution
$$y=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+2t^2+2.$$
Then
$$y=c_1e^{\sin x}+c_2e^{-\sin x}+2\sin^2 x+2.$$

Comment: Brilliant answer! How did you come up with the substitution $t=\sin x$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A great help